# Error during run debug flutter app: B/BL out of range (max +/-128MB) to ''

Tags: flutter, xcode

After installing the new version of Xcode (15.0) with the flutter version 3.13.4 when I launch the debugging of an app the process is interrupted by the following error:

Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): B/BL out of range 135372772 (max +/-128MB) to ''

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Error launching application on iPhone

> UPDATE
> If I remove google_ml_kit from my project, error is resolving

Comment: I can't not remove google_ml_kit. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TARGETS --> Build Settings --> Other Linker Flags --> add -ld64
[image]

Comment: I tried this, but still the same error.

Comment: This one solved my problem! @RodrigoSouza make sure that it is added, because once I added it for the first time, I opened the list and it was not there. So, I had to add it again and I made sure it is in the list by opening it after I added it. Also, make sure that you add it to for the mode you are building the app in

Comment: Note : '-ld64' the first letter is a 'L' lowercase 

Answer (score 3):

More detailed:

1. Runner
2. Targets -> Runner
3. Build Settings
4. Toggle to **Levels**
5. Search for "**other linker**"
6. Double tap in the "**Runner**" column, a list opens
7. At the end of the list is a "**+**"
8. Add "**-ld64**"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note : '-ld64' the first letter is a 'L' lowercase 

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to your podfile
ios >  Runner > Podfile

go to pod_install section and the following code (ps add also this variable or just put the version directly '$iOSVersion'):

```
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=*]"] = "armv7"
    config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = $iOSVersion
  end

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if Gem::Version.new($iOSVersion) > Gem::Version.new(config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'])
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = $iOSVersion
      end
    end
  end
```

then here declare the variable before pod_install section

```
 $iOSVersion = '14.0'
```